# How can I have a dot(.) in my WordPress URL on WAMP Vhost on localhost

Tags: wordpress, apache, wamp

I have defined a `VirtualHost` in my `wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.17/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` file as below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.site.local
DocumentRoot h:/dev/wamp3/www/site
<Directory  "h:/dev/wamp3/www/site">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The WordPress site is available at `www.site.local` when I visit the homepage. 
However, if visit any posts or pages, the URL turns to `http://localhost/site/post-name`, where as I am expecting the URL to be `http://www.site.local/post-name`.

Kindly suggest.

Comment: The problem is not with the virtual host but you seem to have something that redirects you to localhost.

Comment: Yes, in my wp-admin I was still using the `localhost` address.

Comment: You installed if into `http://localhost/site/post-name` and then created a Virtual Host. WP remembers the url that you use to install it into. Delete the WP instance and reinstall it using `www.site.local/install`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your .htaccess file and httpd.conf file for any rewrite rules that might be put in there. If there are none, you likely entered "localhost" as the url in your Wordpress settings. Wordpress always defaults to a single url per page, and will redirect wrongly formed urls. This includes the domain name.

Go to wp-admin in your wordpress installation, then to Settings > General. Change WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) (if possible) to the url you want. If you are using a non-default installation of Wordpress, such settings might be located in wp-config.php or wp-config-local.php.

Comment: Thanks, I was stupid not to update the WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) in the wp-admin.

Answer (score 1):

Check your `wp_options` table (database prefix may differ), and look for the rows where `option_name` name is `siteurl` and `home`. Then check that the `option_value` for each is `http://www.site.local`.

Or run the following query on your database:

```
UPDATE `wp_options` SET `option_value` = 'http://www.site.local' WHERE `option_name` IN ('siteurl', 'home');
```